# Cant generate properties from the List

Tags: java

My entity Bean method

```
 public List<Object> Available_RoomType(String startDate, String EndDate, String name) {
    List<Object> arr_room =  em.createNativeQuery("select  T.* "
            + "from RoomType T"
            + "  inner join Room R on R.RoomTypeID = T.RoomTypeID"
            + "  left join Booking B on B.RoomID = R.RoomID"
            + " where T.Name = '" + name + "' and"
            + "  ((('" + startDate + "' not between B.checkindate and B.checkoutdate) and"
            + "  ('" + EndDate + "' not between B.checkindate and B.checkoutdate)) or"
            + "  (B.BookingID is null))" , Roomtype.class).getResultList();

    return arr_room;
}
```

This query return a row when i run it from the oracle sql developer while just testing it.
 my JSP page .

i use the method of the entity bean and it returns a row with size 0.

```
List<Object> result = guestSession.Available_RoomType(startDateString, endDateString, name);

             List<Roomtype> new_room;
                            List<? extends Object> list = result;
                            new_room = (List<Roomtype>) list;

    %>
    <table>
        <%if(new_room!=null){
                            for(Roomtype r : new_room){%>
        <tr>

            <td><%= r.getName() %></td>
            <td><%= r.getDescription() %></td>
            <td><%= r.getPrice() %></td>
        </tr>

   <%}
        }%>
    </table><%
        }
    %>
```

But when i use it in a foreach, to get the properties, the compiler is jumping at the foreach and no property is displayed.Page comes empty. please help

Comment: Nothing related with issue but you need you use prepared statement as you SQL is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you have a method returning a list. You call the method, iterate on the list, and print each element. And nothing is printed, and no error is thrown. My conclusion is simple: the list is empty. Check your query, and check its arguments. Note that there are many, many things wrong with the code: not respecting naming conventions, not using prepared statements, putting Java code in JSPs, not returning the appropriate type from the method, using strings to hold dates, not indenting the code...